# SVN error E720005, permission denied on binary files

Tags: svn

I am working with svn on a network windows shared drive. Mapped to a drive letter.
Recently I updated from svn 1.7.7 to 1.8.0. This worked well for many repos.
Today I created a new repos and continously having problems with it. No other person is yet accessing it.

I cannot commit binary files. The exact same stuff is working for other projects, but not 
for this new repos.
Adding text files works good, when I commit a binary file, like a .png it fails.

```
Adding  (bin)  SW\hw\system.bit
Transmitting file data .svn: E720005: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E720005: Can't set position pointer in file 'G:\Projekt\P2SW\CASTLE\6_Softw
are\SVN\CTE_5_HW_Self_Bip46\db\txn-protorevs\18-18.rev': Zugriff verweigert
```

So it says "permission denied", but I have permissions, that is sure.
It is as well not the size, i can commit bigger files, when they are text.

Any suggestion is very welcome.
Thanks

Comment: **Never** use shares for file:///-based repositories or Working Copies -it's easy

Comment: Same error on ordinary text files (some `.java` and `.properties` files).  Quite normal hard drive on Windows. Not using the server, just command line or TortiseSVN -- Either fails.  The folder is very small, 41k.  While I could just `copy` and `add`, then `rm` ... I prefer to have the SVN tracking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am working with svn on a network windows shared drive.

No! Bad developer! No donuts for you!

Permissions on Windows is very tricky, especially if shared drives are involved. You should not use the `file://` protocol in this instance. You will have problems with permissions. I don't even use the `file://` on Unix systems even as my private repository. I always launch `svnserve` and use `svn://` as a protocol.

It's simple to setup `svnserve` on Windows as a Windows service. There are quite a few  Windows packages that pack Apache httpd and Subversion together, and then automatically setup almost everything for you. There is no reason to use a shared drive on Windows and use the `file://` protocol.

Check the permissions of all files and subdirectories in your repository. Even though you are the only person using this repository, there is probably a permission issue somewhere. Then go ahead and set everything up as a service.

Comment: Just to note: file:/// on **local drive** is OK, no-headache fast solution for any OS

Comment: I have now worked with this for years without problems. But using the svn:// protocol really worked around the problem.

Comment: @fbenoit ... If you did **Not** find a file permission and I suspect (like me)  you will not have.  Check the status for the _offending_ folder: `svn status dev\experiments\`.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem on a sub folder.  There are only about 8 files and there were no permission problems, not binary files.

Oddly `mv` worked for me on individual files.  Not for the `src/` folder.

My imperitive is to keep a history and using file copy would lose that.  A work-around/alternative is to copy the files and folders then remove them in `SVN`.

```
 d:> md dev\experiments\modelA
 d:> svn add dev\experiments\modelA
 d:> svn cp dev\experiments\*  dev\experiments\modelA\
 A         dev\experiments\modelA\

 d:> svn mv  dev\experiments\build.gradle  dev\experiments\modelA\
 A         dev\experiments\modelA\build.gradle
 D         dev\experiments\build.gradle

 d:> d:> svn mv  dev\experiments\gradle.properties  dev\experiments\modelA\
 A         dev\experiments\modelA\gradle.properties
 D         dev\experiments\gradle.properties

 d:> dir /s/b  dev\experiments
   (shows all your files and folders...)

 d:> svn commit  -m "move project to modelA sub-project" dev\experiments\
 Deleting       dev\experiments\build.gradle
 Deleting       dev\experiments\gradle.properties
 Adding         dev\experiments\modelA\build.gradle
 Adding         dev\experiments\modelA\gradle.properties
 Adding         dev\experiments\modelA\src
 Committing transaction...
 Committed revision 24262.
```

You may notice that I completed my commit of the copied folder and files before removing the `src` folder.  As it happens there was still a problem removing `src`:

```
 d:> svn rm dev\experiments\src
 svn: E155009: Failed to run the WC DB work queue associated with '...\dev\experiments\src', work item 202 (dir-remove experiments/src 1 1)
 svn: E720145: Can't remove directory '...\dev\experiments\src\main\java\au\com\something': The directory is not empty.

 d:> svn cleanup dev
      ( didn't help...)
 d:> 
 d:> rd /s/q dev\experiments\src
 d:> svn status dev\experiments
 D       dev\experiments\src

 d:> svn commit  -m "move project to modelA sub-project" dev\experiments\
 Deleting       dev\experiments\src
 Committing transaction...
 Committed revision XXXXX.
 d:> svn update dev
 Updating 'dev':
```

That has moved the folders and files under `src/` and everything is committed in SVN, with a contiguous history.

The error message about the

```
\src\main\java\au\com\something
```

Probably means that there was an  file under `something/` directory that was not managed by SVN (un-`add`ed so to speak).

At that point, I chose to drop the folder and keep things "clean".  Looking back in the logs and status message output, I discovered there was an uncontrolled file called: `default-log4j.properties.`**`bak`**.

My working hypothesis it that SVN only deletes files under soruce control.  So the `.bak` was this *orphan*.  If that's the case, "Permission Denied" sounds like the wrong error message to report.

Hope that helps you or the next person.